How do I quickly position two windows side by side in Windows Tablet mode with a keyboard shortcut instead of moving the window to the side?
When in Tablet mode:

I cannot just press the shortcut as in How do I quickly position two windows side by side? to split the screen into two windows:

Win + arrow

and then choose the other window next to it from a list of small previews.
I then found out that I can move the windows to their places by clicking on the top of the window and attaching it to the side:


How can I put a window on the left side so that I get the list of windows that I can choose for the right side in Tablet mode with a shortcut instead?
